# Get Shipment Id while creating Shipment in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, shipment

I am creating shipment programmatically. I want to get shipment id what shipment currently creating. See my code,You can understand my question.

```
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment($qty);
if ($shipment) {
$shipment->register();
$shipment->addComment($history_comment, $email && $includeComment);
$shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
try {
    $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
            ->addObject($shipment)
            ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
            ->save();
            }
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("Cannot create an empty shipment for ".$order->getIncrementId());
}
```

I want to get shipment id of this shipment.
Anyone knows how to get..?

Answer (score 1):

I did not try but I guess a `$shipment->getId()` is not working after the `$transactionSave->save()`.

If not, maybe you can use another way to create the shipment: (I found the below code [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-make-order-shipment-from-code/))

```
if($order->canShip()){
    $itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();
    $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order',$order)->prepareShipment($itemQty);
    $shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
    $shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId);
}
```